# Bayes classifier equivalence

Tags: probability

Quoted from my textbook:

> $$p_k(x) = \frac{\pi_k \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \exp(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} (x-\mu_k)^2)}{\sum_{l = 1}^K\pi_l \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \exp(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x-\mu_l)^2)}$$

> The Bayes classifier involves assigning an observation $X=x$ to the class for which the above expression is largest. Taking the log of the above and rearranging the terms, it is not hard to show that this is equivalent to assigning the observation to the class for which

> $$\delta_k = x\frac{\mu_k}{\sigma^2}- \frac{\mu_k^2}{2\sigma^2} + \log(\pi_k)$$

> is largest.

Let $p_k(x) = \frac{A}{B}$. Taking the log of both sides we obtain
$$\log p_k(x) = \log(A) - \log(B).$$

$$\log(A) = x\frac{\mu_k}{\sigma^2}- \frac{\mu_k^2}{2\sigma^2} + \log(\pi_k) - \log(\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma) -\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}.$$

Here I am stuck. Here is what I have tried so far. I can't think of a formula to simplify $\log(B)$.

Comment: Several times you wrote $\sigma_2$ where I think you meant $\sigma^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m slightly confused because you first write that it’s not hard to show but then you seem to describe difficulties you had in showing it. I suspect you forgot to mark the first part of your question as a problem you quoted from elsewhere?

There’s no need to simplify (or even consider) the denominator because it doesn’t depend on $k$.

Comment: I have updated the question. Sorry about the delay. How do I progress. You say the denominator needs no consideration. I don't see what you are trying to say?

Comment: @HMPtwo: You're maximizing with respect to $k$, and $k$ doesn't occur in the denominator. So it's just a constant factor – if you maximize the numerator, it doesn't matter whether you divide it by the constant denominator or not.

Comment: But what about the extra terms I get from manipulating the numerator? How do I go from that to the expression for $\delta$?

Comment: @HMPtwo: Same thing – they don't depend on $k$. $x^2+5$ is largest for the same value of $x$ as $x^2$ is; it doesn't matter whether you add a constant that's independent of $x$.

Comment: I feel stupid. Thanks for clearing that up.